# Future warning message in pandas 2.1.0

Tags: pandas, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have the following code:

```
df['FilterVol'] = np.NaN
df.loc[(df['Volume'] >= df['PrevVolume']), 'FilterVol'] = 1   
df['DaysLast2Week'] = df['FilterVol'].rolling(14, min_periods=1).apply(value_counts)
```

and I'm getting the following future warning messages:
FutureWarning: Calling float on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use float(ser.iloc[0]) instead

FutureWarning: pandas.value_counts is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pd.Series(obj).value_counts() instead.

All this comes after upgrading my system from python 3.9 to 3.11 and a series of upgrades on various packages including pandas. My current version of pandas is 2.1.0.
All columns in my table are dtype: float64.
I've tried a few options but nothing seemed to work. Can anyone tell me how to modify this code to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Use lambda maybe.  Try apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).

Comment: Unfortunately, no change

Comment: What if you quote the method: `.apply('value_counts')`? This actually may be a useful [pandas team ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) where under the hood this rolling calculation still uses the deprecated form. If posting a Git issue, be sure to set up a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply [`Rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) to *turn-off* both `FutureWarning`*s* in one shot :

> `FutureWarning`: *pandas.value_counts is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pd.Series(obj).value_counts() instead.*
> `FutureWarning`: *Calling float on a single element Series is deprecated and will raise a TypeError in the future. Use float(ser.iloc[0]) instead*

```
df["DaysLast2Week"] = df["FilterVol"].rolling(14, min_periods=1).sum()
```

Another variant, without using the intermediate column `FilterVol`:

```
m = df["Volume"].ge(df["PrevVolume"])

df["DaysLast2Week"] = m.mask(~m).rolling(14, min_periods=1).sum()
```

Output :

```
print(df) # with your fixed approach

    Volume  PrevVolume  FilterVol  DaysLast2Week
0      117         392        NaN            NaN
1      315         241        1.0            1.0
2      152         119        1.0            2.0
3      335          80        1.0            3.0
4      283         235        1.0            4.0
..     ...         ...        ...            ...
95     183         159        1.0            5.0
96     346         231        1.0            6.0
97     262         240        1.0            6.0
98     278         296        NaN            6.0
99     274         144        1.0            7.0

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Used input :

```
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Volume": np.random.randint(80, 350, 100),
    "PrevVolume": np.random.randint(65, 400, 100)}
)
```

Comment: Is OP attempting a rolling sum? Or rolling `value_counts`?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan]).value_counts()` is equivalent to `pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan]).sum()`.